# NTFS File-in-Directory-Search Performance

Tags: c#, caching, ntfs, file-search

I'd like to write a cache folder to store computed data, so I don't have to recompute it every time, the same input data comes in. 
So I compute a hash of the input data (e.g. hash over the input file), convert it to a string of allowed characters and want to use it as a file name in a common cache directory, so I can quickly find the computed data using the hash. The amount of cached files will not be extraordinary large (<10000), so I believe using a single folder should not be a problem.

As is often the problem, a power user might want to remove no longer needed cached data in a more intelligent way as to remove the whole cache. So I thought it would be a nice option, to include additional human-readable information in the file name (e.g. original file name of the input file). The cache file name would then have the following structure:

```
<hash>_<info>.<extension>
```

where the `_` is any seperation char that is forbidden in `<hash>`.
Of course, I will care, that there is only one file with the same hash, like the first cache file wins and prevents a new one to be created.

My question is now, does this impact performance for searching a file with the requested hash? Without the additional info I'd have a fixed file name for which I simply search. But with the info added I need to search for a file that starts with the requested hash, e.g. using a wildcard as in `<hash>_*.<extension>`.

As far as I understand, NTFS uses a B+Tree to organize file names inside a directory. So it would traverse the tree in any case, whether I search for a fixed file name, or for one with wildcards. So I guess the important part has to be at the beginning of the file name, and the unimportant part at the end. But is there any performance hit for searching with wildcards? And if, is there any possibility to get around this problem?

If important, I'm writing it in C#, using something like `Directory.EnumerateFiles()`, but I'm open for other suggestions.

Comment: Why not store the data in a DB?

Comment: First of all, I'd disable creation of 8.3 file names, see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/121007

Comment: I guess, DB is not a good option, since the data is potentially quite large (several 10MB per cache entry). And it goes against my wish to enable a power user to selectively delete entries in an easy way.

Answer (score 0):

NTFS could be smart enough to do prefix lookups for non-metacharacter text (like "hash_*.ext"). So you could >find< the file but to do an open would mean traversing things all over again.

Also, adding on the extra information reduces the density of entries in each BTree page meaning there may be more pages to search when looking for a file.

I'd keep the names as short as possible so as to address your open performance needs and stick the human-readable info into an alternate data stream.  You wouldn't get to see that info when doing "dir", but it could be arbitrarily large.